# clients connecting to TCP iterative server even after backlog queue is full

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

Here's an iterative server I've created to handle basic client-server chat application.

I am trying to run *TCPserver* on a terminal window and *TCPclient* on multiple terminal windows.

More than 5 the clients are getting connected(neither getting blocked nor failing. They immediately `connect` successfully) despite of the fact that I set the `backlog` value (`listen` system call) in server socket to be 5.

I expected that no more than 5 clients could be connected(only 1 would be accepted at a time).

Is my understanding of the *backlog* value set in the `listen` system call wrong?
Please clarify.

> int listen(int sockfd, int backlog);
>
> The backlog argument defines the maximum length  to  which  the queue of pending connections for sockfd may grow.

Here are the actual programs for reference.

## TCPserver.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>

#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#define BACKLOG 5

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    //create the server socket
    int sd;
    sd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sd==-1)
    {
        perror("Some error occured in creating the socket: ");   
        //Interprets the value of errno as an error message, and prints it to stderr 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
        printf("Socket created!\n");

    //define the server address
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    //inet_addr("192.168.137.163");//INADDR_ANY;

    //bind the socket to our specified IP and port
    int bind_status = bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
    if(bind_status == -1)
    {
        perror("An error occurred in binding the socket: " );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
        printf("Bind Successful!\n");


    //listen for connections
    int listen_status = listen(sd, BACKLOG);    
    if(listen_status == -1)
    {
        perror("Error occured in listening: ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 
    else
        printf("Server is listening!\n");

    while(1)
    {
        //Accept a connection and create a new socket for this connection
        int new_sd;
        struct sockaddr_in client_address;
        int client_address_size = sizeof(client_address);

        new_sd= accept(sd, (struct sockaddr*) &client_address, &client_address_size);
        if(new_sd==-1)
        {
            perror("Can't accept connection: ");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
            printf("Accept successful!\nA new client has connected. He'll soon send you a message.\n (You can chat or say \"exit\" to stop chatting)\n\n");
    

        //send a message to the client
        char buffer[256] = "Welcome to the server, lets chat! \n (You can chat or say \"exit\" to stop chatting)\n";
        send(new_sd,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);

        //start chat
        while(1)
        {
            memset(buffer,0,256);
            int n = recv(new_sd, buffer, sizeof(buffer),0);
            if(n==-1 || strcmp(buffer,"exit\n")==0 || strcmp(buffer,"exit")==0)
                break;
            printf("\nclient said: %s\n",buffer);

            memset(buffer,0,256);
            printf("Say something: ");
            fgets(buffer,256,stdin);
            n = send(new_sd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
            if(n==-1 || strcmp(buffer,"exit\n")==0)
                break;
        }

        //close the sockets
        close(new_sd);
        printf("\nConnection ended. waiting for new connection now . . .\n");
    }

    close(sd);

    return 0;
}
```

and Here's the client

## TCPclient.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>

#include<netinet/in.h>

#include<unistd.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    //create the socket
    int sd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    if(sd==-1)
    {
        perror("Some error occurred in creating the socket: ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
        printf("Socket created!\n");

    //specify an address for the socket
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");//INADDR_ANY;

    //Connect to the server
    int connection_status = connect(sd,(struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));

    if(connection_status == -1)
    {
        perror("There was an error connecting to the remote socket: ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
        printf("Connected to the server! Waiting in the queue for the server to accept the connection...\n");
        
    char buffer[256];
    //get the connection message from the server
    recv(sd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    printf("Server Said: %s\n", buffer);

    //start chat
    while(1)
    {
        memset(buffer,0,256);
        printf("Say something: ");
        fgets(buffer,256,stdin);
        int n = send(sd,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
        if(n==-1 || strcmp(buffer,"exit\n")==0)
            break;       

        memset(buffer,0,256);
        n = recv(sd,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
        if(n==-1 || strcmp(buffer,"exit\n")==0)
            break;

        printf("\nServer said: %s\n",buffer);
    }

    //close the socket
    close(sd);

    return 0;
}
```

Someone suggested I check if `syncookies` have been enabled on my system. When I perform `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies`, I get `1`.

Comment: How are you determining more than 5?

Comment: @jxh I am running 7to10 clients on different terminal windows and all are able to connect at the same time.

Comment: Are you expecting a `connect` failure from the client? Why wouldn't you expect the client to block until it is able to connect?

Comment: @yano Only 1 of the connections can be accepted at a time, its an iterative server. Try running the programs.

Comment: @jxh What's wrong with expecting a `connect` failure from the client?

Comment: Nothing wrong with expecting failure, as long as you are OK with it not failing. :-) It won't happen unless it takes a really long time. If your listen queue already has 5 pending, those beyond 5 will just be waiting for their SYN-ACK. Those beyond 5 clients will behave as if their initial ACK was dropped and so will periodically retransmit the ACK until SYN-ACK comes back (they got into the queue), or the retransmit timeout occurs.

Comment: @jxh Those beyond 5 are getting connected immediately(`connect` returning success immediately instead of waiting for the retransmit timeout and eventually failing), even when 5 pending are already in the queue.

Comment: the `connect` in client is neither blocking nor failing. It's returning with a successful connection.

Comment: Use netstat to figure out the TCP state of the socket. See if those clients really are in CONNECTED state or actually in some other state.

Comment: @jxh Checked with 8 clients.All 8 clients are in ESTABLISHED state and  the server is in SYN_RECV.

Comment: This means for your TCP stack, full handshake is always being done. Probably you will see a difference if your client attempts to send some data after `connect` returns. Like, the ones in the listen queue will get some ACKs back, while the ones not in the listen queue will not get ACKs. Alternatively, your system has decided 5 is too small, and increased it automagically for you.

Comment: Oh, your system probably supports syncookies. `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies` on linux.

Comment: @jxh It prints 1. What's that?

Comment: @ARBY Since the connection probably only took a tiny fraction of a second, you would have to look *very* carefully to conclude that more than 5 connected at the same time. Most likely they in fact connected in groups of 5 or less. Note that you `accept` a connection only *after* the connection is made and the `listen` backlog affects the process of making a connection only.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: The server only handles one connection at a time. The client blocks waiting for user input before finishing its interaction with the server. He ARBY is complaining that when he connects with one client in one window and does not type anything into it, he is able to keep connecting to the server beyond 5.

Comment: @jxh Right, each of those connections probably completes before the next one starts. So while they're all connected at the same time, they're not pending at the same time. A connection is only pending during the TCP connect handshake.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The listen man page seems clear to me that the listen backlog holds completely established sockets waiting to be accepted.

Comment: @jxh Yes, It was changed with linux 2.2

Comment: @jxh The documentation is not clear, not all operating systems do it the same way, and as ARBY pointed out, Linux's behavior changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system has enabled [SYN cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_cookies), which allows the TCP stack to behave as if it has a very large listen queue. It was designed to mitigate DOS via SYN flooding.

The [`listen` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html) states about the `backlog` argument:

> When `syncookies` are enabled
>          there is no logical maximum length and this setting is ignored.

If you really want no more than 5 pending clients to wait on the server, you will have to manually maintain your own queue, and close new connections if your queue is full.

<sub>Note that this solution does not actually affect the behavior of the operating systems listen queue. The solution is to continually clear the listen queue of any backlog and close those connections if your server already has 5 pending connections in its own queue.</sub>

Probably in your case, the easiest way to achieve that is with two threads. One doing the accepting, the other handling connections off the queue.

The fragment below illustrates this in pseudo-code. It assumes proper thread mutual exclusion and signaling is performed by the queue operations.

```
accepting_thread () {
    int queue_count = 0;

    for (;;) {
        new_conn = accept();
        if (q_size(q) < 5) {
            q_enqueue(q, new_conn);
        } else {
            close(new_conn);
        }
    }
}

handling_thread () {
    for (;;) {
        new_conn = q_dequeue(q);
        /* ... */
        close(new_conn);
     }
}
```

To get clients that are terminated early to see a reset, you can enable the linger option with a 0 timeout value. Most TCP stacks will cause a RST to be generated when the socket is closed.

Comment: This code won't work as advertised, as there is still the apparently very large listen queue in front of it.

Comment: It just closes the connections if there are already 5 pending connections.

Comment: Are you sure it's because of SYN cookies and the system has not automatically chosen a higher value of backlog?

Comment: @jxh Pending in the application. It doesn't know about the possibly very large number of connections pending in the backlog queue. All you've done is increment that by 5.

Comment: @EJP: The accepting thread keeps accepting and closing if the application queue is full. Since the OP wants the connect to "fail" if it is not in the queue, this is the best the server can do to achieve that.

Comment: @ARBY: You have already verified SYN cookies are enabled. Based on how SYN cookies work, this would be the observed behavior of clients. And, the `listen` man page documents the behavior.

Comment: @jxh No it isn't. All you've accomplished is adding 5 to the backlog queue. The OP's requirement is better met without this code than with it.

Comment: Your answer seems most sane and logical. I'll accept it till I find a better answer.

Comment: @jxh And this code will not accomplish that purpose. There is already a backlog queue of indeterminate length. All you've done is add another queue of length five after it. It is completely and utterly futile.

Comment: @ARBY The part about SYN cookies was sane and logical. He ruined it when he added this pointless code.

Comment: @EJP: Are you saying the `close` in the `accepting_thread` is pointless? Why?

Comment: @jxh I am saying that adding a queue after another queue does not reduce the length of the first queue.

Comment: @EJP: Closing connections clears an otherwise unbounded queue of clients waiting to connect, does it not?

Comment: @jxh No it doesn't. You're not making sense. Accepting connections removes them from the backlog queue, and closing them closes them. An extra queue placed after the backlog queue does not  affect the size of the backlog queue. Can you show for example that your code accepts and closes excess connections faster than they can possibly arrive?

Comment: @EJP: That is not the purpose of the code. The purpose is simply to send a busy signal in the form of early termination rather than in the form of waiting in line for their turn to be handled.

Comment: So the purpose of the code doesn't answer the purpose of the OP.

Answer (score 3):

The backlog is the "queue of *pending* connections" -- once you accept a connection, it is no longer pending, and comes off the queue, leaving room for 5 more pending connections.

If you want to limit to 5 connections, then you need to count how many you have accepted (and not closed). Any more attempts to connect would then wait in the queue.

Comment: Correct. Furthermore, requesting a listen backlog of 5 is no guarantee that you got a listen backlog of 5. The platform can adjust it up or down, in this case almost certainly up, and you have no way of knowing what the actual backlog value is.

Comment: @EJP _platform can adjust it up or down . . no way of knowing what the actual backlog value is_, can you please quote a reference.

Comment: @ARBY if you're really interested, you could do worse than read [this](http://veithen.github.io/2014/01/01/how-tcp-backlog-works-in-linux.html).

Comment: @Raman See [http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/listen.html](Posix).